# Необработанное исключение типа "System.NullReferenceException"

Tags: c#

```
foreach (Label label in BlockLabels)
{
  label.BackColor = _blockEmptyColor[0];
}
```

При компиляции вылазит ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.NullReferenceException" в My1Tetris.exe
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Программирую немного, поэтому никак не могу понять, в чем проблема.

Comment: При компиляции эта ошибка появляться не может. Она появляется во время выполнения, и скорее всего значит, что вы забыли инициализировать один из объектов, упоминающихся в строке, на которой происходит ошибка.

Comment: Ругается на label - как его инициализировать?

Comment: `label = new Label();` но, боюсь, это не то, что Вам надо. Как заполняется контейнер `BlockLabels`?